# How to insert child element referencing foreign key in NHibernate?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I am still new to Fluent NHibernate. Not sure how I should approach this.

I have two entities:

```
 public class Student
{
    public virtual Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public virtual String Dept_id { get; set; }
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int Age { get; set; }
    public virtual String Address { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
public class Department
{
    public virtual int Dept_id { get; set; }
    public virtual String Dept_name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public Department()
    {
        Students = new List<Student>();
    }
}
```

and the mappings are  :

```
public class DepartmentMap : ClassMap<Department>
{
    public DepartmentMap()
    {
        Table("Department");
        Id(x => x.Dept_id).Column("Dept_id");
        Map(x => x.Dept_name).Column("Dept_name");

        HasMany(x => x.Students).KeyColumn("Student_id").Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}
public class StudentMap :ClassMap<Student>
{
    public StudentMap() 
    {
        Table("Student");
        Id(x => x.StudentId).Column("Student_id").GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Age);
        Map(x => x.Address);
        Map(x => x.Dept_id).Column("Dept_id");

        References(x => x.Department).Column("Dept_id").Not.Nullable();

    }
}
```

when i am trying to insert as :

```
        StudentRepository rep = new StudentRepository();
        Student s = new Student();
        s.Name = txtname.Text;
        s.Age = int.Parse(txtage.Text);
        s.Address = txtaddress.Text;
        s.Dept_id = dddept.SelectedItem.Value;
        rep.Add(s);
```

It's giving me error as:

```
{"not-null property references a null or transient value nHibernateTest.Domain.Student.Department"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating your new Student you need to set the Department not just the Id.  Is there a reason you need a separate property for this?  I would remove this property from your entity and from your mapping class and just leave in the Department reference.  If you need the Department Id you can just reference it via Student.Department.Dept_id.

Basically you are trying to insert an entity with a null value in a foreign key column.  You would need to change your creation to something like this:

```
    StudentRepository rep = new StudentRepository();
    Student s = new Student();
    s.Name = txtname.Text;
    s.Age = int.Parse(txtage.Text);
    s.Address = txtaddress.Text;
    s.Department = SelectedDepartment;  //SelectedDepartment is the actual department entity from the database
    rep.Add(s);
```

Comment: well i understnd tht but how can i then get the selectdepartment ? i mean can it b just an blank object for the Department class ?

Comment: How are you getting a list of your department ids?  Most likely you will get the department through your repositories as I see you are using repositories above.

Comment: @Cole hi i tried as Mariusz suggested  now the problem is its giving error as : Invalid index 5 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=5

Comment: @Joy, Did you remove the Map(x => x.Dept_id).Column("Dept_id"); ?

Comment: @Cole okay !! my bad i dint remove the mapping .. but how can i just reference it ? while like i wanna bind it to a gridview ? then i really need to get the department id can u provide me with an example ? if u really can ?

Comment: okie got it... i did it in the Student class itself by  public virtual int Dept_id {  get { return Department.Dept_id; }} 

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

If you will be doing this like is in your post you will get an error because you want to send empty data of Department object. As Cole W says. You need to compare id of Department which you want to add with id of existing Department from database.

I will define SelectedDepartment from Cole W answer. You can add it to repository.

```
//repository
public Department SelectedDepartment(int id)
{
Department getDepartment = session.Get<Department>(id);
return getDepartment;
}
//controller
 s.Department = rep.SelectedDepartment(1) //for example department with id = 1
```

Comment: tried to do that . now its giving me error as : Invalid index 5 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=5.

Comment: Did you change line s.Dept_id = dddept.SelectedItem.Value to  s.Department = rep.SelectedDepartment(1) ? If it is not working try to remove Map(x => x.Dept_id).Column("Dept_id");
from your mapping. I never had that error before but [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2009/03/19/nhibernate-and-invalid-index-n-for-this-sqlparametercollection-with-count-n-error.aspx) is example of solving it. This is first googled link.

Comment: thanks for helping .. dint actually got the point first time.. new in nhibernate :)